# Fit text on svg textpath

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am building [a chart](http://codepen.io/bumbeishvili/pen/xVBbdZ?editors=1010) using D3.js, which shows some info about employee's competencies

as you can see, some text is larger than container element size, because of that, part of the text, is cut

I tried to change text font-size dinamically , but this trial was not very successfull :/

now my code looks like this

```
.attr('font-size', function (d) {
              var defaultSize = 14;
              var angleForOneLetter = 1.14; // 
              console.log('angle=' + d.data.angle);
              console.log('length=' + d.data.name.length);
              console.log('str=' + d.data.name);

          if (angleForOneLetter * d.data.name.length > d.data.angle) {
              angleForOneLetter = d.data.angle / (d.data.name.length + 2);
              console.log('letter angle=' + angleForOneLetter + '\n \n');

              if (angleForOneLetter > 0.8) return 10;

              if (angleForOneLetter > 0.7) return 10;
              if (angleForOneLetter > 0.5) return 8;
              if (angleForOneLetter > 0.4) return 6;
              if (angleForOneLetter > 0.3) return 5;
              return 3;
          }
          console.log('letter angle=' + angleForOneLetter + '\n \n');
          return defaultSize;

});
```

and it works only  case  ,when  chart radius is `580px;`

I want a better way to achieve same goal and fit text to borders, when chart radius varies

you can play with code on [codepen](http://codepen.io/bumbeishvili/pen/xVBbdZ?editors=1010)

Comment: Is your end goal here just to scale the text down so that it always fits it's bounds?  Most of the text will be unread-ably small if this is how you go.  Instead I would keep all text the same size and `...` those that overflow.  Then I'd add a mouseover to show the full text.

Comment: yes, this is one of the options , but I still would like to know, how to scale text to fit bounds in my case

Comment: @Mark  how can I know, if text overflows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the appearance of the text and just want to force it to fit, you could do it with:

```
...
.style('font-size', 14)
.each(function (d, i) {
  var self = d3.select(this),
    pathLen = d3.select("#outerArc" + i).node().getTotalLength();

    self.attr("textLength", pathLen)
    self.attr("lengthAdjust", "spacingAndGlyphs");
    self.attr("y", "50%");
    self.attr("x", "50%");
  });
```

Updated [codpen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXzEGe?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like :

```
.text(function (d) {
    if (d.yourTextString.length > attrs.width/20) {
        //use a specific size;
    }
    else if (d.yourTextString.length > attrs.width/40) {
        //use another specific size;
    }
    else if (d.yourTextString.length > attrs.width/60) { ...
```

It's easily usable on any chart, since it depends on the chart size, then you can adapt/change the /20 /40 /60 to fit your needs, you can use like 3 - 4 different cases and it should be enough, if you don't need to perfectly fill the chart with text. 
I used something like this few weeks ago, worked for me, not sure if it's enough here.